# According to my teachers solutions this is incorrect. Does anyone know why?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

$\int cos^4(x)*sin^2(x)dx $

$ = \int cos^2(x)*[cos^2(x)sin^2(x)]dx $

$ = \frac{1}{4}\int cos^2(x)*sin(2x) dx$

$ =\frac{1}{4} \int cos^2(x)*sin(2x)dx $

$ = \frac{1}{8} \int [1 + cos(2x)]sin(2x)dx$

$ = \frac{1}{8} \int[ sin(2x)+ cos(2x)sin(2x)]dx$

$ = \frac{1}{8}\int sin(2x)dx + \frac{1}{16} \int sin(4x)dx$

$ = -\frac{1}{16}cos(2x) - \frac{1}{64}cos(4x) + C$

EDIT: forgot the minus sign in front of the antiderivatives of $sin(2x)$ and $sin(4x)$.

Comment: what is the justification of the second $=$ sign? Perhaps there should be a $\sin^2(2x)$ in there.

Comment: Ah. That makes sense haha. Thank you so much !

Comment: the second equality should still have $\sin^{\color{#C00}{2}}(2x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\text{This was the easiest way I could figure to do it.} \\[10pt]
\int \cos^4(x)\sin^2(x)dx \\
= \int \cos^2(x)[\cos^2(x)\sin^2(x)]dx \\
= \frac{1}{4}\int \cos^2(x)\sin^2(2x)dx \\
= \frac{1}{8}\int [1+\cos(2x)]\sin^2(2x)dx \\
= \frac{1}{8}\int [\sin^2(2x)+\sin^2(2x)\cos(2x)]dx \\
= \frac{1}{8}\int \sin^2(2x)dx + \frac{1}{8}\int\sin^2(2x)\cos(2x)dx \\
= \frac{1}{16}\int [1-\cos(4x)]dx + \frac{1}{8}\int\sin^2(2x)\cos(2x)dx \\[10pt]
\text{Now I just handle those parts separately and give them separate integration} \\ \text{constants that I can combine in the final expression.} \\[10pt]
\frac{1}{16}\int [1-\cos(4x)]dx = \frac{1}{16}x - \frac{1}{64}\sin(4x) + C_1\\
\frac{1}{8}\int\sin^2(2x)\cos(2x)dx = \frac{1}{48}\sin^3(2x) + C_2 \\[10pt]
\text{So the answer is as follows.}\\[10pt]
\int \cos^4(x)\sin^2(x)dx = \frac{1}{16}x - \frac{1}{64}\sin(4x) + \frac{1}{48}\sin^3(2x) + C \\[10pt]
\text{If you happen to not like the cubed power in there, that can be dealt with by}\\ \text{further manipulation.}\\[10pt]
\sin^3(2x) = \sin^2(2x)\sin(2x) = [1-\cos^2(2x)]\sin(2x) = \sin(2x) - \cos^2(2x)\sin(2x)\\
= \sin(2x) - \frac{1}{2}[1+\cos(4x)]\sin(2x) = \frac{1}{2}\sin(2x) - \frac{1}{2}\cos(4x)\sin(2x)\\[10pt]
\text{That product at the end can just be dealt with by a product-to-sum identity.}\\[10pt]
\cos(4x)\sin(2x) = \frac{1}{2}\sin(6x) - \frac{1}{2}\sin(2x) \\[10pt]
\text{The cubed power is then just as below.}\\[10pt]
\sin^3(2x) = \frac{3}{4}\sin(2x) - \frac{1}{4}\sin(6x) \\[10pt]
\text{Finally, the answer to the indefinite integral is as follows.}\\[10pt]
\int \cos^4(x)\sin^2(x)dx = \frac{1}{16}x + \frac{1}{64}\sin(2x) - \frac{1}{64}\sin(4x) - \frac{1}{192}\sin(6x) + C\\
$

Comment: That is the correct answer! Thank you very much!